Dirac analysis for constrained system with explicit time-dependence
Consider the following Lagrangian with explicit time-dependence through the function $\omega_{ij}(t)$:
$$
L(t)=\frac{1}{2}\xi_i(t)\omega_{ij}(t)\dot\xi_j(t)-V(\xi(t)).
$$
The $\xi_i(t)$ are the dynamical variables. We assume that $i=1,...,2N$.
The E-L EOMs are
$$
\dot\xi_i=\omega^{(A)-1}_{ij}(\xi_k\dot\omega_{kj}/2+\partial_j V)
$$
where $\omega^{(A)}$ is the anti-symmetric part of $\omega$, which we assume is invertible. The Dirac analysis of this system gives me $2N$ constraints:
$$
\varphi_i=p_i-\xi_j\omega_{ji}/2
$$
which are all second class. The matrix of P.Bs is
$$
\{\varphi_i,\varphi_j\}=\omega^{(A)}_{ij}
$$
The Hamiltonian is $H=V(\xi)$. The Hamilton EOM is
$$
\dot\xi_i=\{\xi_i,H\}_D=\omega^{(A)-1}_{ij}\partial_j V
$$
where $\{,\}_D$ is the Dirac bracket.
My problem, however, is that this Hamilton EOM doesn't coincide with the E-L EOM due to the time-dependence of $\omega$. Does that mean that a Hamiltonian formulation of this Langragian system doesn't exist!?

Are you sure you haven't skipped a dot in your "kinetic" term?

@CosmasZachos no it's meant to be a 1st order Lagrangian


OP's system is described by the Lagrangian 1-form
$$ \mathbb{L}(z;\dot{z};t)~=~ \sum_{I=1}^{2n} \vartheta_I(z;t)  \mathrm{d}z^I- H(z;t)\mathrm{d}t.\tag{1}$$
No need to go through the full Dirac-Bergmann analysis of constraints. The Faddeev-Jackiw method suffice. The Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations are
$$\begin{align} \dot{z}^I ~\approx~& \sum_{J=1}^{2n}\omega^{IJ}\left(\partial_J H + \partial_0\vartheta_J\right)\cr
 ~=~& \{z^I,H\} + \sum_{J=1}^{2n}\omega^{IJ}\partial_0\vartheta_J, \end{align}\tag{2} $$
where
$$ \omega_{IJ}~:=~\partial_I\vartheta_J-(I\leftrightarrow J)\tag{3} $$
is the (components of the) symplectic 2-form. OP is essentially noticing that the EL eqs. (2) are the standard Hamilton's equations up to an extra term because of the explicit time dependence of the symplectic potential 1-form $\vartheta_I(z;t)$. We interpret eqs. (2) to be the appropriate/correct generalization of Hamilton's equations to this case with explicit time dependence.

By the way, it is natural to generalize to contact geometry on a $2n+1$-dimensional contact manifold, i.e. view $t=z^0$ as an extra dynamical variable, and the 0-component $\vartheta_0=-H$ of the presymplectic potential 1-form as minus the Hamiltonian, so that the Lagrangian 1-form becomes
$$ \mathbb{L}~=~ \sum_{I=0}^{2n} \vartheta_I  \mathrm{d}z^I.\tag{4}$$
This formulation is manifestly invariant under choice of world-line (WL) parametrization.



Ok so it seems we need to generalise Hamilton's equation. But now consider the quantum theory. The quantum EOM that the operators satisfy can simply be taken to be operator version of the classical E-L EOMs. But how would states evolve? $e^{-iHt}$ cannot be the evolution operator because for operators it would give the Heisenberg EOMs (which are the quantum version of Hamiltons equations) which are wrong in this case (because of the time dependence of $\omega$).
